Minimizing a certain sum using integer partitions
Before the problem itself, I want to say that I do not know how to address the problem, which is why it is hard for me to categorize it in a specific topic: I believe it could be Elementary Number Theory, Combinatorics or Discrete Optimization. In any case, it would be very helpful if someone could suggest me how to categorize it.
Problem
Let $a,b \in N$ be coprime, with $a<b$. Consider $P=\{p_1,\dots,p_k\} $ a partition of $a$, that is, $p_1 + \dots + p_k=a$. Suppose we choose a partition such that

$p_i$ is not coprime with $b$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$

Among all partitions $P$ of $a$ that satisfy the above, find the minimum of $\sum_1^k \frac{LCM(b,p_i)}{p_i}$.
Inspiration: I came up with this question while reading a popular science book from Adrián Paenza, an Argentinian mathematician. His question was much simpler:
Suppose we have a group of 12 people ($b=12$) and 7 pizzas ($a=7$). We want to find a way to cut the least number of slices between the 12 pizzas, while giving each person the same amount of pizza. One option is to consider two groups: the first one has $3$ pizzas ($p_1=3$) cut into $4$ slices each ($LCM(b,p_1)/p_1$), and the second one has $4$ ($p_2=4$) pizzas cut into $3$ slices each ($LCM(b,p_2)/p_2$). Here the sum would be $4+3=7$.
Maybe the general problem can be solved for lower values of $a$ and $b$ with an algorithm, but probably not for higher values. I am trying to find a way to start thinking about the problem, to find (maybe, in the best case) a formula for any $a$ and $b$, though it seems quite hard.

For fixed $a$ and $b$ you can solve the problem via integer linear programming (specifically, "integer equality knapsack") as follows.  Let $$P=\{p\in\{1,\dots,b\}: \gcd(p,b)\not= 1\}$$ be the set of candidate parts.  For $p\in P$, let nonnegative integer decision variable $x_p$ be the number of times part $p$ appears in the partition. The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{p\in P} \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(p,b)}{p} x_p = \sum_{p\in P} \frac{b}{\gcd(p,b)} x_p$$ subject to
\begin{align}
\sum_{p\in P} p x_p &= a
\end{align}
For your example $(a,b)=(7,12)$, the problem is to minimize
$$6x_2 + 4x_3 + 3x_4 + 2x_6 + 3x_8 + 4x_9 + 6x_{10} + x_{12}$$
subject to $$2x_2 + 3x_3 + 4x_4 + 6x_6 + 8x_8 + 9x_9 + 10x_{10} + 12x_{12} = 7,$$
with optimal solution $$x_3 = x_4 = 1, x_2 = x_6 = x_8 = x_9 = x_{10} = x_{12} = 0.$$
Here are the results for $b\le 50$ (with infeasible cases omitted):
\begin{matrix}a & b & \min \\\hline5 & 6 & 5\\5 & 12 & 10\\5 & 18 & 15\\5 & 24 & 20\\5 & 36 & 30\\
5 & 42 & 35\\5 & 48 & 40\\7 & 10 & 7\\7 & 12 & 7\\7 & 18 & 15\\7 & 20 & 14\\7 & 24 & 14\\7 & 30 &
21\\7 & 36 & 21\\7 & 40 & 28\\7 & 48 & 28\\7 & 50 & 35\\8 & 15 & 8\\8 & 45 & 24\\9 & 10 & 7\\9 & 1
4 & 9\\9 & 20 & 9\\9 & 28 & 18\\9 & 40 & 18\\9 & 50 & 35\\10 & 21 & 10\\11 & 12 & 7\\11 & 14 & 9\\
11 & 15 & 8\\11 & 18 & 11\\11 & 20 & 14\\11 & 24 & 11\\11 & 28 & 11\\11 & 30 & 11\\11 & 36 & 21\\1
1 & 40 & 28\\11 & 42 & 27\\11 & 45 & 24\\11 & 48 & 22\\11 & 50 & 35\\12 & 35 & 12\\13 & 14 & 9\\13
 & 15 & 8\\13 & 18 & 11\\13 & 20 & 9\\13 & 21 & 10\\13 & 22 & 13\\13 & 24 & 14\\13 & 28 & 18\\13 &
 30 & 13\\13 & 36 & 13\\13 & 40 & 13\\13 & 42 & 13\\13 & 44 & 26\\13 & 45 & 24\\13 & 48 & 28\\13 &
 50 & 35\\14 & 15 & 8\\14 & 33 & 14\\14 & 45 & 14\\15 & 22 & 13\\15 & 26 & 15\\15 & 28 & 11\\15 &
44 & 15\\16 & 21 & 10\\16 & 39 & 16\\16 & 45 & 24\\17 & 18 & 11\\17 & 20 & 9\\17 & 21 & 10\\17 & 2
2 & 13\\17 & 24 & 11\\17 & 26 & 15\\17 & 28 & 18\\17 & 30 & 11\\17 & 33 & 14\\17 & 35 & 12\\17 & 3
6 & 13\\17 & 40 & 18\\17 & 42 & 17\\17 & 44 & 26\\17 & 45 & 24\\17 & 48 & 22\\17 & 50 & 35\\19 & 2
0 & 9\\19 & 21 & 10\\19 & 22 & 13\\19 & 24 & 11\\19 & 26 & 15\\19 & 28 & 11\\19 & 30 & 13\\19 & 34
 & 19\\19 & 35 & 12\\19 & 36 & 19\\19 & 39 & 16\\19 & 40 & 18\\19 & 42 & 13\\19 & 44 & 15\\19 & 45
 & 14\\19 & 48 & 19\\19 & 50 & 35\\20 & 21 & 10\\20 & 33 & 14\\21 & 22 & 13\\21 & 26 & 15\\21 & 34
 & 19\\21 & 38 & 21\\21 & 40 & 13\\21 & 44 & 26\\21 & 50 & 35\\22 & 35 & 12\\22 & 39 & 16\\22 & 45
 & 24\\23 & 24 & 11\\23 & 26 & 15\\23 & 28 & 11\\23 & 30 & 11\\23 & 33 & 14\\23 & 34 & 19\\23 & 36
 & 19\\23 & 38 & 21\\23 & 40 & 13\\23 & 42 & 17\\23 & 44 & 15\\23 & 45 & 14\\23 & 48 & 22\\23 & 50
 & 35\\24 & 35 & 12\\25 & 26 & 15\\25 & 28 & 11\\25 & 33 & 14\\25 & 34 & 19\\25 & 36 & 13\\25 & 38
 & 21\\25 & 39 & 16\\25 & 42 & 13\\25 & 44 & 26\\25 & 46 & 25\\25 & 48 & 19\\26 & 33 & 14\\26 & 35
 & 12\\26 & 45 & 24\\27 & 28 & 11\\27 & 34 & 19\\27 & 35 & 12\\27 & 38 & 21\\27 & 40 & 18\\27 & 44
 & 15\\27 & 46 & 25\\27 & 50 & 27\\28 & 33 & 14\\28 & 39 & 16\\28 & 45 & 14\\29 & 30 & 11\\29 & 33
 & 14\\29 & 34 & 19\\29 & 35 & 12\\29 & 36 & 13\\29 & 38 & 21\\29 & 39 & 16\\29 & 40 & 13\\29 & 42
 & 17\\29 & 44 & 26\\29 & 45 & 14\\29 & 46 & 25\\29 & 48 & 22\\29 & 50 & 27\\31 & 33 & 14\\31 & 34
 & 19\\31 & 35 & 12\\31 & 36 & 13\\31 & 38 & 21\\31 & 39 & 16\\31 & 40 & 13\\31 & 42 & 13\\31 & 44
 & 15\\31 & 45 & 24\\31 & 46 & 25\\31 & 48 & 19\\31 & 50 & 27\\32 & 33 & 14\\32 & 35 & 12\\32 & 39
 & 16\\32 & 45 & 14\\33 & 34 & 19\\33 & 35 & 12\\33 & 38 & 21\\33 & 40 & 13\\33 & 46 & 25\\33 & 50
 & 27\\34 & 35 & 12\\34 & 39 & 16\\34 & 45 & 14\\35 & 36 & 13\\35 & 38 & 21\\35 & 39 & 16\\35 & 44
 & 15\\35 & 46 & 25\\35 & 48 & 19\\37 & 38 & 21\\37 & 39 & 16\\37 & 40 & 13\\37 & 42 & 13\\37 & 44
 & 15\\37 & 45 & 14\\37 & 46 & 25\\37 & 48 & 19\\37 & 50 & 27\\38 & 39 & 16\\38 & 45 & 14\\39 & 40
 & 13\\39 & 44 & 15\\39 & 46 & 25\\39 & 50 & 27\\41 & 42 & 12\\41 & 44 & 15\\41 & 45 & 14\\41 & 46
 & 25\\41 & 48 & 19\\41 & 50 & 27\\43 & 44 & 15\\43 & 45 & 14\\43 & 46 & 25\\43 & 48 & 19\\43 & 50
 & 27\\44 & 45 & 14\\45 & 46 & 25\\47 & 48 & 19\\47 & 50 & 27\\49 & 50 & 27\\\end{matrix}

Thank you very much!
